# Определить значение слова "сербиш"

Tags: этимология

Что означает слово "сербиш": житель какой-то местности или представитель какой-то народности?

Comment: Слово услышано от... (прочитано в)...

Answer (score 1):

Сербиш (serbisch) - это сербский по-немецки, возможно имеется в виду это. Для более полного ответа требуется контекст.

Comment: Здравствуйте!  Сербишем  назвали  моего  родственника,  выходца  из  Витебской  губернии(Латгалии)  по  фамилии  Шнигирь(Шнигерь?.Спасибо!

Comment: Кто назвал? В каком контексте?